# Marklogic (Nodejs API) - Search documents that match 2 (or more) conditions in object array attribute

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

My documents are stored in JSON in marklogic like this (I remove useless attributes for my case):

```
{
  documentId: '',
  languages: [{
    locale: 'en_UK',
    content: {
      translated: 'true',
    }
  }, {
    locale: 'de_DE',
    content: {
      translated: 'false',
    }
  }, {...}],
}
```

**edit:** It seem that my 'useless' attributes cause some problems. Here my detailed object.

```
{
  documentId: '',
  /* 4 attrs */,
  languages: [{
      locale: 'en_UK',
      attr: '',
      content: {
      /* 14 attrs */,
        translated: true,
        /* 2 or 4 attrs */,
      }
    }, {
      locale: 'de_DE',
      attr: '',
      content: {
        /* 14 attrs */,
        translated: false,
        /* 2 or 4 attrs */,
      }
    }, {...}
  ],
  /* 0 or 2 attrs */
}
```

I try to find all documents that have at least one object in *languages* where *locale = 'en_UK'* and *content.translated = true* with

```
var query =
  qb.where(
    qb.directory('myDocuments'),
    qb.scope(
      qb.property('languages'),
      qb.and(
        qb.scope(qb.property('code'), qb.term('en_UK')),
        qb.scope(qb.property('translated'), qb.term('true'))
      ),
      qb.fragmentScope('properties')
    )
  );
```

and

```
qb.where(
  qb.directory(myDocuments'),
  qb.scope(qb.property('languages'),
    qb.propertiesFragment(
      qb.value(
        qb.property('languages'),
        qb.and(
          qb.scope(qb.property('code'), qb.term('en_UK')),
          qb.scope(qb.property('translated'), qb.term('true'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

but in both cases, the query return documents that match the 2 conditions in the whole document, not in each object of *languages* array.

I read the documentation but I haven't found anything. Do you have any ideas how I can make my query ?

**edit:** I try a near query but it doesn't work. It doesn't match the good documents.

```
qb.where(
  qb.directory(config.marklogicConfiguration.product),
  qb.scope(qb.property('languages'),
    qb.near(
      qb.and(
        qb.scope(qb.property('code'), qb.term('ja_JP')),
        qb.scope(qb.property('translatedInTheLanguage'), qb.term('true'))
      ),
      1,
      qb.weight(0),
      qb.ordered(true)
    )
  )
)
```

I will ask if I can change my object structure.

**edit2:** Finally, I use Xquery request to get the correct result.

```
xdmp:directory("/product/direcory/")/languages[code eq "ja_JP" and content/translated eq "true"] ! root(.)
```

In my case, I use eq for *content/translated* condition because my boolean is stored as a string.
*!root(.)*: return the whole object, not only the language objects that match the condition *[code eq "ja_JP" and content/translated eq "true"]*

Comment: XPath expressions like in edit2 will always run with filtered mode, and that might scale less well.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [near-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_48512), one of the [Location Qualifiers available in structured queries](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_92125). Provide your locale and translated queries, specify a `distance: 1` and `ordered: true`. Note that whether this works will depend on where the "useless attributes" that you removed were.

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to introduce another layer to your structure.

```
{
  documentId: '',
  languages: [{
    item: {
      locale: 'en_UK',
      content: {
        translated: 'true',
      }
    }
  }, {
    item: {
      locale: 'de_DE',
      content: {
        translated: 'false',
      }
    }
  }, {...}],
}
```

That's not real pretty, but it would let you run a [container-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_87231).