# Why is searching arrays using cts different than searching arrays using node api?

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I have a question similar to this question:
[Marklogic (Nodejs API) - Search documents that match 2 (or more) conditions in object array attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573243/marklogic-nodejs-api-search-documents-that-match-2-or-more-conditions-in-o)

I have the following document:

```
{
  "address": [
    { "type": "mailing",
      "street": "1001 Main Street",
      "city": "Springfield",
      "state": "MO"
    },
    { "type": "location",
      "street": "989 First Street",
      "city": "Johnstone",
      "state": "WY"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the following code within query console, it correctly does not return the document:

```
'use strict';

const queryText = 
  cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("address", cts.andQuery([
    cts.jsonPropertyWordQuery("city", "Johnstone"),
    cts.jsonPropertyWordQuery("state", "MO")
  ]));

cts.search(queryText);
```

When I run this code in Node.js, it does return the document because it appears to combine all of the array nodes when evaluating.

```
const queryText =
  qb.scope(qb.property("address"), qb.and(
    qb.word("city","Johnstone"),
    qb.word("state","MO")
  ));

const query = qb.where(queryText);
```

Is there a way I can get cts functionality using the Node API?  I would prefer to use the Node API versus using invoke on a server side javascript query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the SJS searches run *filtered*, which will remove any false positive results. You can toggle that behavior by adding explicit options to the SJS search:

```
cts.search(queryText, "unfiltered");
```

By default, the Node.js queries are run [*unfiltered*](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_89797), which means that you may encounter false positive results.

In order to get your Node.js search running *filtered*, add the `filtered` search option to your query:

```
const query = qb.where(queryText)
  .withOptions({search:['filtered']});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have confirmed that the above works.  I had a feeling it might be related to filtering after I posed my question.  I am surprised the two are not in-sync (i.e. that sjs and node don't have the same default).  I did not find this mentioned in the online docs or the API.

Comment: Yes, the Java API, which sits on top of the REST API just like the Node.js API, has a section in the guide that explicitly explains the default options https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/query-options#id_66439. I don’t think that the Node.js documentation currently has an equivalent section.